# Let's design a community promotion ad!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[Community promotion ads](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/31/community-promotion-ads/) are small images shown in a site's sidebar to promote various related things - site blogs, events, and other Stack Exchange sites, to name a few. Only graduated sites (and [a few beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248214/274942)) have them - so most betas don't. However, I'm not looking for us to host ads, but to *make* one. People are trickling into our new, quiet portion of the Internet, and it's important to let everyone know what this site is all about.

Here are some select formatting details from Stack Exchange, which are repeated in the submission threads for ads on other sites (e.g. [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4377/627)):

> - The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
> - If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

The precise details for submission can be ironed out when the ad is submitted to various sites.

We obviously don't have a site design yet, and we should expect that for a really long time - long after graduation starts. However, we do have some options. For instance, we could use the default icon from the site proposal:

[image: Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange]

Alternatively, we could come up with our own design.

We also have to consider which sites we want to put the ad on. [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) and [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) are possibilities that come to mind.

Comment: Since we're a site for *humans*, we can probably put the ad wherever we'd like, considering that we adapt each ad for each site.

Comment: I'd also suggest placing ads on [English.se] and [ELL.se], because we do get questions about interpersonal skills instead of the language sometimes.

Comment: @NVZ I already have [ELU](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10039/59258) and [ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3461/8790) ads which I can replace with the good art when we have them. Though the ELL one is currently at -2 so it would probably be better to make a new one...

Comment: So are you saying we can submit our ideas?

Comment: @bjskistad Absolutely.

Comment: Please, to everyone - I know that we are excited and want to share this site near and far but we need to really think and decide which sites we want to target - and these ads should probably be tailored towards those sites directly. As a user on ELL, I don't see there being a crossover between this site and theirs and I doubt there's one for ELU, either. We've mentioned a few sites this is good for and I think that's part of the brainstorming we need to do.

Comment: @Catija I would look to put something on travel. Maybe I'll make an ad for that :)

Answer (score 4):

We can go for something like this.

[image]

The background includes people communicating directly and online. It has a nice quote. Though, this quote can be changed.

Comment: This is great. I have two suggestions: Change "Interpersonal Skills Q & A" to "Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange" (so it's clear we're an SE site) and make that person standing in the middle a bit wider. He or she seems oddly thing.

Comment: Sure I will change that. The man in the middle is looking odd because the image compression.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for putting in all this effort.

Comment: Decent concept! But at 50% size it's not legible enough. Maybe make the quote unbold? And why isn't the text centred?

Comment: @curiousdannii I can make the quote unbold, but I think it doesn't need to be centered.

Comment: @AJ Sure, it doesn't *need* to be uncentred, but it's right up against the left site and there's *lots* of space on the right

Comment: @curiousdannii Let's see if doing unbold it removes the space.

Answer (score 4):

I took a try at this as well, but keep in mind my work was inspired by A J's initial designs. I tried to go for some complimentary colors, just enough text and I personally think the ad could really use a call to action button as it triggers people more to click.

I prefer the second picture, but maybe without the background. I quite like the white background of the first one.

If you have any additions or changes to the text, please let me know. Copywriting is certainly not my strong point.

[image: Option 2]

[image: Option 1]

Comment: These both look really nice. I personally prefer the top one though I do think the copy could be improved. I'd rather we avoid the word "advice" because we're not really here to get or give advice - we're here to get answers. This may tie somewhat into our discussion about how/whether we need to be able to support answers with evidence - either references or personal experience with the solution.

Comment: I like the top one aswell, maybe add something about other peoples experience (i.e. instead of advice).